# Getting Error 401 when getting weather from OpenWeatherMap using C#

Tags: c#, apache, asp.net-web-api

Below is my code of the Web API. I am getting a System.Net.WebException(The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.) when I pass a city in URL of the API.

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetWeatherReport(string cityName)
{
    string json = string.Empty;
    string createRequest = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cityName + "&mode=xml&units=metric&appid=APIKEY";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(createRequest);
    request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
            JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            jsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
            string data  = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(data);
            json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc).Replace("@", "");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to OpenWeatherMaps FAQ on Error 401's, they have the following to say:

---

You can get the error 401 in the following cases:

- You did not specify your API key in API request.
- You are using wrong API key in API request. Please, check your right API key in personal account.
- You have FREE subscription and try to get access to our paid services (for example, 16 days/daily forecast API, any historical weather data, Weather maps 2.0, etc). Please, check your tariff in your personal account and pay attention at our price and condition.

Starting from 9 October 2015 our API requires a valid APPID for access. Note that this does **not** mean that our API is subscription-only now - please take a minute to register a **FREE** account to receive a key.

**For FOSS developers:** we welcome free and open source software and are willing to help you. If you want to use OWM data in your free software application please register an API key and file a ticket describing your application and API key registered. OWM will review your request lift access limits for your key if used in open source application.

---

From the looks of it you are supplying an API key and the particular data you are trying to fetch is part of the free offering, I would double check your API Key as the above has suggested.